# (dis)advantages of sessions vs cookies

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I need some details about sessions. What are the disadvantages of session variables?
Between cookies and sessions, which one is better?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not going to touch on security here as Infotekka already went into it quite a bit.  It seems like you are asking whether you should use a SESSION or COOKIE as if they are alternatives to one another.

They are not.  They server (this was a typo..but I'm leaving it cuz it's a nice pun) different purposes.

As HTTP is stateless, PHP (and others) offer the ability to simulate a state machine in your application through the use of a Session.  If you did not do this, you would have to use POST/GET between every page to keep the data consistent, and if the user goes to another page on their own that data will be lost!  So without a SESSION, you wouldn't be able to have a user logged in to your site .. at least not very consistently.

To summarize, SESSION is used to keep data between multiple pages of your site without using HTTP for an extended period of time.  That's what it is used for.

I suppose you could use COOKIE to do this, but it is much more complicated as cookie, especially when dealing with objects serialized to the session.  COOKIEs that are set also cannot be accessed until the next page load and must be set before any output by the script (like any other header).

Sessions should be just that -- the session that the user has when they sit down at their computer for however long to do work on the site.  When the leave, the session ends.

Cookies should be used to store simple data for a long period of time.  If they go to the website a lot, they might want their username to be remembered for them, so it can be stored as a cookie.  Just be mindful of the security issues noted by Infotekka.

EDIT: Finally, I should add that COOKIEs are transmitted on every page request between the user and browser.  More Cookies means more page load time.

Comment: A very good point about the effective impossibility of reliably trying to maintain data across posts / gets

Answer (score 6):

That's a pretty open ended question, but I think the most important thing that you should consider when using the session in PHP is how easy it is to hijack.  The PHP session stores all of its values in the server cache, where it is retrieved based on a session id that is written to a cookie on the client.  As long as that session is active, a client that connects with that session id will be granted access to that session.

There are some scary programs out there, like firesheep, that can show you just how easy it is to nab a session id and make it your own.  If you are going to base any security on that session, you need to make certain that EVERYTHING you do is over SSL, and you should build in some second tier of validation to make sure your session hasn't been hijacked.

All that being said, the session is a great place to store persistent values that you will need to access over the lifecycle of the user's application experience.

Comment: A valid point, but this argument works even better against cookies then sessions.

Comment: Agreed, but without cookies there is no session

Comment: This answer implies to me that you shouldn't use the session because of how easy it is to hijack because of the PHPSESSID cookie .. which in turn implies you should use cookies, but that wouldn't make sense because of how easy /they/ are to hijack.. It does bring up a good point about security, but it doesn't discuss sessions vs. cookies..

Comment: I think you're missing the point: in order for PHP to identify the owner of the session, it writes a cookie to the client - I never meant to imply that other cookies should be used instead, only that you should be aware of this vulnerability and secure it with SSL.

Comment: @tandu to infotekkas point the further action would be to also not utilize the default PHPSESSID cookie name as that is the given a hijacker would be looking at. Regardless there is no safer route then to utilize SSL.

Comment: I'm not saying that Infotekka is wrong, he just didn't address the question which was ostensibly asking for an alternative to sessions (e.g. cookies).  I'm not going to downvote this or anything, though..it's a good pots.  @a.stgeorge reread his post more carefully.  People can hijack /any/ cookie equally whether it is PHPSESSID or not because all cookies are sent as normal headers.

Comment: -1: First cookies and sessions are not interchangeable, second, its not programs like firesheep which are scary - it's the number of badly written sites they can compromise. And I'd be very interested to hear what you think "some second tier of security" might be. And the session is not the place to store data relating to the cumulative user experience - only for the current session.

Comment: Don't forget other session protection features such as session_regenerate_id