# Login system without cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I got a PHP login system plugin from Internet, It does not use manually created cookie, only session is used. (the cookies related with sessions are automatically created)

Is it secure that a to use such a login system  ?

Comment: Sessions usually use cookies, too.

Comment: Session with no cookie? Pray tell, how does that work?

Comment: @deceze session ID in a query parameter? `:P`

Comment: @Matt In which case: `D:`

Answer (score 8):

Yes a session login system is secure, even more so than a cookie-only approach.
A standard session uses a cookie in PHP, but it *can* be done without cookies, which is fun, if you're a masochist. [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies) if you like pain.

Just google *"session benefits"* or *"session vs cookie"*. And read through this page on [sessions without cookies](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/php-questions/can-sessions-work-without-cookies/), Especially the last bit (disadvantages).
Note that security *of the client* is the main issue here: sharing a link could, if you're not careful, mean sharing a session. Think about having a client with a hijacked browser logging in, his/her session ID is now public property. Same goes for XSS attacks.
So you'll have to log the client's IP, which can change from time to time. You'll have to check for concurrent connections time and time again... argh, the horror... there's just too much you need to check.

Also check this post on SO, for more details on both sessions and cookies:

[(dis)advantages of sessions vs cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190953/disadvantages-of-sessions-vs-cookies)

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. He's not asking "should I store sensitive data in cookies?" but "can I have a session management system without cookies?" to which the answer is "in theory yes, but you probably don't want it"

Comment: To whomever down-voted, Care to explain why? @Pekka웃 pointed out something, which I believe to have adressed

Comment: You say not using cookies are more secure. The opposite is true

Comment: @Anigel: So passing the session id via the url is more secure according to you? storing session id's in history is more secure? what about XSS attacks, browser hijacks, or JS  [messing with browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) a cookie isn't secure, but it isn't as dangerous as passing data via the URI

Comment: I guess you have not read my answer I say exactly the opposite not using cookies is less secure you say it is more secure

Comment: @Anigel: I'm not: _"And read through this page on sessions without cookies, Especially the last bit (disadvantages). Note that security of the client is the main issue here: sharing a link could, if you're not careful, mean sharing a session"_ <-- directly from my answer. That's the same as saying: _No cookies, No safe_

Comment: Your answer has gone through several revisions and changed significantly since it was downvoted at which time you said something along the lines of using sessions without cookies is more secure than using cookies. Again I point you to my answer which broadly agrees with what your answer is NOW saying

Comment: @Anigel: Well, Pekka pointed out my answer might be unclear/ambiguous, so I edited, that's the point. [At no point, though, did I say no-cookies was the safer route](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17449927/revisions), I said sessions are safer than a cookie-only login system. Even so, the downvote, now, is not justified. I've addressed the ambiguity issue

Comment: At the time it was downvoted you did not specify cookie-only approach in the answer which was indeed ambiguous, so at that time the downvote was justified. It has already been removed in light of your edits after the downvote was cast.

Comment: For login noobs like me, to clarify, my understanding is 2 experts, after an entertaining SO argument, agree: Most secure is: 1) session with cookies, then 2) session with no cookies which means you must pass the ID in the URL (risk if someone else gets this URL, they hijack your session, ie they are now you on that website), then 3) cookie-only login (incredibly complicated to do, horribly insecure!). And this is same with whatever programming language you use for login. Try disabling cookies and logging into Amazon, Facebook etc. see what message they give you and when, fun to see I think.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways of using sessions.

1. The sessionID is stored in a cookie on the users computer
2. The sessionID is passed back to the server on every page load as a query parameter.

Now as it is just the session ID that is stored in the cookie anyway this does not make it insecure.

However if you use method 2 and pass the sessionID as a query parameter, it is less secure as the session ID WILL be stored in the browser history even when the browser is reopened at a later date where a session cookie would be deleted when the user closed the browser.

The confusion comes with not understanding how sessions work. Sessions using cookies, do not store any of the session information on the client computer, only the ID of the session. The session information is stored on the server no matter if you choose the cookie based or cookieless method of handling sessions

Answer (score -4):

Yes, Sessions are more secure and will be more difficult for hackers to attack your site, 
while a cookie can be easily edited to fit the hackers needs.

Comment: Depending on your definition of hijack, sessions can easily be hijacked, especially if using a cookieless session what can't happen easily is session information be changed

Comment: sessions send cookie with session ID, and that cookie may get hijacked (aka stolen) in transit. Obviously that would help somebody get access to account and so on. And I cant see anyone storing session variables in the cookies. The best I found is for secure(r) systems is do some addotional checks. such as if user agent changed. Sure they aren't 100% secure but definitely help.